# "Mustache" syntax alternative for Vue template when using Pug language

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pug, nuxt.js

`"Mustache"` syntax allows defining data like this:

```html
<template>
    <Window>
        <template v-slot:title >
            {{title}}
        </template>
    </Window>
</template>
```

but compilation with `lang='pug'` fails:

```html
<template lang='pug'>
    <Window>
        <template v-slot:title >
            {{title}}
        </template>
    </Window>
</template>
```

With this error:

> Module build fails: unexpected text "{{" ...

Other templates without `mustache` syntax usage build fine with `lang='pug'`. What's the **Pug**'s alternative to `mustache` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the contents of your Pug template isn't actually Pug syntax, but that aside:

In Pug, [plaintext](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) should be inside a tag (e.g., `span`) or prefixed with the pipe character:

```html
<template lang="pug">
Window
  template(v-slot:title="")
    | {{title}}
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-voice-fu5l1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FDemo.vue&theme=dark)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Could you also please point out why it has to be `template(v-slot:title="")`, but not `template(v-slot=title)`? I thought **Pug** requires passing `key=value` pairs like that.